# VBA code that runs like goto functions: "Ctrl-[" and "F5"

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any VBA code that simulates the normal `goto` Excel function <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>  and <kbd>F5</kbd>?

**Further elaboration with an example:**

In this [Problem.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4cYOk7H1SuXbzVqX3dWdWtmOVU/edit) are two worksheets—`Alpha` and `Beta`.

I would like a code to

1. Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> on cell `A2` of the `Alpha` worksheet (i.e. grab the Beta!B5 reference in the cell)
2. So as to jump to cell `B5` of the `Beta` worksheet (using the Beta!B5 reference, make the jump)
3. Move one cell to the right, i.e. `C5` of the `Beta` worksheet and shade that cell yellow
4. And finally do a <kbd>F5</kbd> to go back to cell `A2` of the `Alpha` worksheet

I have Googled for 2 hours on various keywords like `goto`, `ctrl-[`, `F5`, `previous selection`, etc. to no avail.

Additional note:

I am trying to simulate the goto functions Ctrl-[ and F5 such that any active cell (with a link to another cell in another sheet) I am on, the VBA code can perform the jump, do the color shading and jump back to the original sheet. *i.e. the below codes are too restrictive*

```
Sub JumpColourJump()
    Worksheets("Beta").Range("B5").Offset(, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Worksheets("Alpha").Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

The code should be **flexible** to jump to whichever sheet in the same file or in another file that the active cell is referring to.

Comment: Problem.xlsx is not publicly visible (registration required), so I've removed the link. Please reupload somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry guys. I just edited the link to the file. It should work now.

Comment: SkyDrive has the same problem: http://i.imgur.com/DpwIT5s.png ...Though it's still better than some random forum link.

Comment: Apologies again.. I have put up a new link to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code can be produced by recording a macro, but the more complex parts appear to be:

- Navigating to the first cell which references the selected cell - [this post on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/219185/138849) looks like it contains some good advice
- Returning to the previous sheet - you could just take a reference to the active sheet at the start of your function, then restore it afterwards, i.e.:

```
Dim initalSheet As Worksheet
' Take a reference to the current sheet
Set initialSheet = ActiveSheet

' *** Perform changes here ***

' Return to the initially selected sheet
initialSheet.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in order to go back and forth between the pages will work.

```
'follow local hyperlink
Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Alpha").Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1
'color the cell to the right
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
'return using the same method
```

You can then use `ActiveCell.Offset(row, col)` to get the right cell and perform the operations, and return using the same method.

---

In order to return to the previous location, you could save it in a variable,

```
Dim returnSheet As String, returnCell As String
returnSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
returnCell = CStr(ActiveCell.Address(False, False))
'Jump to cell, do your magic
Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets(returnSheet).Range(returnCell)
```

**or** for several jumps from cell-to-cell a class-module acting **like a stack** implementing push & pop functions would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks Cthulhu. Ctrl-[ is equal to Application.Goto Reference:=CStr(ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1)   How about the "return" jump 'F5'?

Comment: @user2180895 You could store the value of your current location in a variable (or a collection if it is multiple nested jumps) and retrace your path.

Comment: This code can display the Goto Dialog box: Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaGoto).Show if there is a way to code the clicking of "ok", then it would be a F5 + Enter function

Comment: @user2180895 I don't think that is possible. Either way, I'd recommend you do it in VBA code without interacting with UI elements, similar to the way it is detailed above.